# Sorting a REALLY BIG delimited text file in UNIX / VMS

Tags: sorting

I am going to sort a **REALLY BIG delimited text file**, say 250Mb (or a bunch of files of more or less than 250Mb) . It have 37 fields, and I need to sort it by 5 fields, for example 1st, 4th, 5th, 6th 7th fields. **Under Unix / VMS, do I have a good option to do this FAST?** I can write COBOL program.
           Now I am trying to sort them using the below command, but it already run for a long time and just not going to finished.

Thank you.

The command I used: time sort -t ',' -o sorted.txt +0 -1 +4 -5 +5 -6 +6 -7 +22 -23 *.DAT_gprscdr_ftpd

Comment: Ask this question at stackoverflow.com

Comment: Look at this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930044/why-unix-sort-command-could-sort-a-very-large-file you might be able to use the script in there.

Comment: What's wrong with the shell script you provided?  The unix sort **is** fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this question really should be in another SE-site, but here is my take on this issue.

**1)** Isn't the basic sort you provided in
    your question fast enough? How fast it should
    be? My 2 year old desktop sorts
    270MB of Apache access log files in
    21 seconds.

**2)** If that is not fast enough, you can try to first sorting each file individually and then merge them with "sort -m"

**3)** If not fast enough and you have more than one CPU/core, parallelize (sp?) the process with [GNU Parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/)

**4)** If still not fast enough and you have more machines available, parallelize the sorting process on multilple machines with [GNU Parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#description)

Answer (score 0):

you can load the data in MySQL database (LOAD command) and do what you want